# Cast on androidTV

Tags: google-cast, android-tv

I have an app which is perfectly working with a classic Chromecast dongle. I am using my own custom channel.

However the Chromecast's icon does not appear when using my AndroidTV as it should. AndroidTV is actually supposed to support the Cast protocol. It's working on several apps such as YouTube but it is not working on most of the app and on mine.

From the Google doc ( https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv) :

> Your existing Cast application runs on Android TV with no additional effort

So I guess I should have nothing to do ...

The same doc is also talking about the specific media namespace :

> urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media

but I don't think I need to use this namespace for my app to display the icon.

If you have any idea, please help me on this.

Comment: Is your app published? If not, have you registered your Android TV for your app?

Comment: Yes my app is published. I am very aware about the whitelisting and register process.

Comment: What device is it? ADT-1, Nexus Player, an OEM TV..?

Comment: Testing on a ADT-1. I think it could be the issue.

Comment: I believe since the ADT-1 is an early developer kit, not everything is fully supported. See [*Which Cast apps are supported on ADT-1?*](https://developer.android.com/tv/adt-1/index.html#cast).